# Usar https con diferentes puertos

Tags: apache2, https, openerp

Buen día a todos. Mi  problema es el siguiente:
Tengo un servidor openerp que redirijo del puerto 8069 al puerto 80 y tengo un sistema web al que entro en el puerto 81.

Ahora necesito agregar ssl pero quiero seguir igual, usando https://openerpserver.com y https://openerpserver.com:81 , la primera parte ya la logré, pero he estado investigando y no encuentro cómo entrar con esta: https://openerpserver.com:81

Hice esto en el conf de apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName openerpserver
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName openerpserver

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://local_ip:8069/$1 [P]
  ProxyPassReverse / http://local_ip:8069/

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.key

</VirtualHost>


 <VirtualHost *:81>

      ServerName servererp.com
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
      RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

 </VirtualHost>
```

Pero me dice que el puerto 443 ya está ocupado.

Gracias a todos,

Gaby L.

Answer (score 0):

Modificar el archivo

```
«/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl»
```

y modificar el número de puerto para HTTPS.

Comment: Hola, agregué el puerto 81 como puerto seguro https, y mandé el puerto 8075 al 443. No sé si lo hice bien , pero funciona :D.

Comment: Si te funciona, perfecto. No es lo normal. Marca la pregunta como respondida. Y señala con un cotejo y voto positivo la respuesta que te ayudó, así mejoramos cada día.